# Distinguish timeout and no-data cases

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase, nosql

Currently in my project i faced an issue that there is no difference between two situations when requesting data:

1. When there is actually no data in db (for requested params)
2. When timeout occurs (or for example when VPN connection is lost)

In both cases method:

```
object Get(string key)
    Member of Enyim.Caching.IMemcachedClient
```

returns simply null. I'd like to catch an exception or something in the second case to distinguish these two cases.

For `SocketPool` `receiveTimeout` is set to `{00:00:01}`, but even being expired exception is not thrown as i expect. Could you advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two interfaces that `MemcachedClient` implements: `IMemcachedClient` and `IMemcachedResultsClient`. Each basic method on `IMemcachedClient` has an equivalent `ExecuteXXX` method on the other interface that returns more detailed results.

You can do:

`var result = client.ExecuteGet<MyType>(key);`

result will be an `IGetOperationResult` that you can query for various status codes, or get the message for logs or whatever.

For the reasons you specify, I tend to always prefer the `ExecuteXXX()` cals over the simpler `XXX()` ones, even though it can be a bit more code to use them.

Comment: Thanks, that the answer! The thing I should add is that I didn't find these methods until updated the CouchBase.dll to version 1.1 or later